# Create hive table for schema less avro files

Tags: hive, avro, apache-crunch

I have multiple  avro files and each file have a STRING in it. Each avro file is a single row. How can I write hive table to consume all the avro files located in a single directory .
Each file has a big number in it and hence I do not have any json kind of schema that I can relate too. I might be wrong when I say schema less . But I cannot find a way for hive to understand this data. This might be very simple but I am lost since I tried numerous different ways without success. I created tables pointing to json schema as avro uri, but this is not the case here. 
For more context files were written using crunch api

```
final Path outcomesVersionPath = ...
pipeline.write(fruit.keys(), To.avroFile(outcomesVersionPath));
```

I tried following query which creates table but does not read data properly

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_table
ROW FORMAT
SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs:///somePath/directory_with_Ids'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data set only has one `STRING` field then you should be able to read it from Hive with a single column called `data` (or whatever you would like) by changing your DDL to:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_table
(data STRING)
ROW FORMAT
SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs:///somePath/directory_with_Ids'
```

And then read the data with:

```
SELECT data FROM test_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use avro utilities jar to see avro schema for any given binary file [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line/#retrieve-avro-schema-from-binary-avro)!
Then just link the schema file while creating a table.